# Error Session File Driver in CodeIgniter 3

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am a new developer of CodeInger, last few month I had developed my project with PHP framework which is called CodeIgniter. So my problem was that when I tried to upgrade my project from version 2 to 3 I've found one concerning error which was about session.

**Note**: I am using Google Cloud Hosting.

Here is a message  :

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: mkdir(): The local filesystem is readonly, mkdir failed

Filename: drivers/Session_files_driver.php

Line Number: 117

Backtrace:

File: /base/data/home/apps/s~chatomuk-staging/13.383916973498394810/index.php
Line: 292
Function: require_once
```

I have tries more than 3 hours to solve it but there was no answer.

could anyone tell me what is the problem ?

url : http://chatomuk-staging.appspot.com/

Comment: *what* have you tried in the three hours you've been trying to fix it? We don't want to give you suggestions you *know* don't work.

Comment: $config['sess_save_path'] = NULL; Try to set this one.

Comment: I have already do it but still not work :$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_save_path'] = NULL;
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;

Comment: give 0755 permission to your ci folder

Comment: $config['sess_driver'] = 'database';
$config['sess_save_path'] = 'ci_sessions'; add this into config.php file

Comment: Now, I have already changed it , but I still found the erro. could you tell me why should I set 
   
 
$config['sess_driver'] = 'database'; and  $config['sess_save_path'] = 'ci_sessions' ? you can go to my website again and see the new error.

Comment: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  `ci_sessions` (
 session_id varchar(40) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
 ip_address varchar(45) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
 user_agent varchar(120) NOT NULL,
 last_activity int(10) unsigned DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
 user_data text NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (session_id),
 KEY `last_activity_idx` (`last_activity`)
);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to set this two parameter in your config.php file

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'database'; 
$config['sess_save_path'] = 'ci_sessions'; 
$config['sess_use_database'] = TRUE;
```

Before that you check you session table is exist or not in your database
if not exist the create

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ci_sessions ( session_id varchar(40) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL, ip_address varchar(45) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL, user_agent varchar(120) NOT NULL, last_activity int(10) unsigned DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL, user_data text NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (session_id), KEY last_activity_idx (last_activity) );
```

Answer (score 2):

While this may of solved your problem it wasn't exactly the problem you are faced with in your error message.

It looks like in your config you set the session driver as a file based session driver.  This means you need to set the path for your session.  You also need to at the very least make sure the directory is writable by the user with permission running your php scripts usually `www-data` on linux boxes.  Usually something like this.

```
sudo chmod g+w _ci_sessions
```

And if ownership isn't set properly something like this is probably safe.

```
sudo chown root:www-data _ci_sessions
```

You also should include a path for the driver like this.

```
$config['sess_save_path'] = APPPATH . '_ci_sessions';
```

Then make sure the directory has a path similar to this and is created.  All your sessions will be stored here.

```
/var/www/html/application/_ci_sessions
```

I will add you only need to do this if you have the driver set to files like this.

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
```

Also make sure you use APPPATH environmental variable as absolute paths are required.